# Separate login form student, faculty and admin in angular using firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I m developing a project, online attendance system, regarding this, I want to know how to make separate login for student component, faculty component, and admin component so that student with his credential cannot log in to faculty and vice versa. Maybe it is called as role based authentication. Someone help me in writing code for the above case in angular using firestore.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't about completing your homework or giving suggestions. Show what you did and ask your doubts.

Comment: This question is too generic. Please come up with your precise problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Role-Based Access Control.

You can take advantage of Cloud Firestore's data model as well as custom security rules to implement role-based access control in your app.Suppose you are building a collaborative writing application in which users can create "stories" and "comments" with the following security requirements:

- Each story has one owner and can be shared with "writers",
  "commenters", and "readers".
- Readers can only see stories and comments. They cannot edit anything.
- Commenters have all the access of readers, and they can also add
  comments to a story.
- Writers have all the access of commenters, and they can also edit
  story content.
- Owners can edit any part of a story as well as control the access of
  other users.

Assume your app has a `stories` collection where each document represents a story. Each story also has a `comments` subcollection where each document is a comment on that story.

To keep track of access roles, add a roles field which is a map of user IDs to roles:

**/stories/{storyid}**

```
{
  title: "A Great Story",
  content: "Once upon a time ...",
  roles: {
    thomas: "owner",
    james: "reader",
    john: "writer",
    avan: "commenter"
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comments contain only two fields, the author's user ID and some content:

**/stories/{storyid}/comments/{commentid}**

```
{
  user: "thomas",
  content: "I think this is a great story!"
}
```

For setting up the rules, have a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) for detailed infomation.